# Serial <> Ethernet converter and SerialPort.Write()

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to achieve maximum throughput on a serial port. I believe my C# code is causing a buffer overrun condition. SerialPort.Write() is usually a blocking method.

The problem is the unit/driver doing the Ethernet to Serial conversion doesn't block for the duration it takes for it to transmit the message. It doesn't appear to block at at all. Until it ends up blocking forever once too much data is written to it too fast. Then the SerialPort needs to be disposed before it will work again. Another issue is BytesToWrite always == 0 directly after thw write. Driver???

So, how do I get around this issue?

I tried doing a Sleep directly after the write for the duration it would take send the message out, but it doesn't work.

```
com.Write(buffer, 0, length);
double sleepTime = ((length + 1) * .000572916667) * 1000; //11 bits, 19.2K baud
Thread.Sleep((int) sleepTime);
```

I realize there may be some delay between when the unit receives the message and when it sends it out the COM port. Perhaps this is the reason why the driver does not block the .Write call?

I could wait for the message to be ack'd by the node. Problem is I'm dealing with thousands of nodes and some messages are broadcast globally. It is not feasible to wait for everyone to ack. What to do?

Any ideas?

Comment: There's very little we can offer unless you tell use what model of converter you're using.  Are you writing to a virtual serial port that actually streams the data over TCP to a remote serial port?  Or writing to a serial port that converts the data to ethernet?  There are some big holes missing in your description.

Comment: http://www.perle.com/products/IOLAN-SDS-Rack-Terminal-Server.shtml

Comment: @rare: So is this C# code running on the SDS Rack?  Normally I would expect you to make a TCP connection to the rack, and it would then convert to serial, but in that case you'd be talking about sockets in your code, not serial ports.

Comment: @Ben: Well, I'm using their driver which makes it look like a SerialPort. It handles the TCP protocol issues. I want to keep the code as generic as possible. As in not tied to any specific protocol that a Serial to Ethernet unit may require. Why? Perhaps I will use mobo COM ports, PCI COM port boards, or who knows what in the future.

Comment: @rare: So they install a VCP (Virtual COM Port) under the Ports group in Device Manager?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, they call it "Perle TruePort Adapter (192.168.1.100)" in the device manager. It's under Multi-port serial adapters in the tree.

Comment: @rare: Hmm, I've seen similar things before but never used that particular one.  Have you checked the device properties (both the multi-serial adapter, and the COMxy under Ports) to see if there's any configurable parameters there?

Comment: @Ben: I tried turning on the 16550 buffers for each port. That didn't work. Probably doesn't support it. It's got settings for soft inbound/outbound flow control. None of those settings worked either,not that I'd expect them to. Other than that, I don't see anything else. Is there a possible software-side workaround? The PCI card from National Intruments I have works fine.

Comment: @Ben: Do you know of a serial to Ethernet unit where the VCP driver supports blocking when doing a SerialPort.Write()?

Comment: @rare: Sorry, I don't.  The reason your write is non-blocking is because the data is going out across Ethernet, which is many times faster than the serial port.  The serial transmit buffers aren't on your computer, they're on the terminal server.  And fetching the buffer status on every write would slow down the works (although it still would be faster than waiting for an ack to round-trip through the serial port).  Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for the advice. I'll contact support.

Comment: As a side note, the Thread.Sleep() is notoriously inaccurate, and often will have a resolution of 15ms, possibly causing your initial code to fail.